# CSS linked to aspx page is Not loading in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, html, css, firefox

I am creating a aspx page using visual studio 2008.
and linking it with a css via

but when i build it page opens with only html format and CSS look and feel is not applying
Please tell what can i do to make to correct.
But its working correct on IE...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried validating the resulting HTML page and the CSS file ([HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)) ([CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/))

If validating and resolving errors does not help, please post your HTML and CSS.